# Remove all styling from Primefaces components?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to remove all styling from Primefaces components? I mean, the component set is good but having to manually override every tiny bit of each component to make the component style fit the overall design of my application isn't good. I can't use hours on using Firebug to find which classes etc it uses and all that.

So is there no way to remove this and only use the components for their functionality and provide your own design instead of being forced to use the default....or one of the "themes"?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Set `primefaces.THEME` context parameter to `none` and you'll get a functional ui with no styles.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You don't need to spend hours editing styles. Styling of PrimeFaces is done via shared styles like `ui-widget-header`, `ui-widget-content` which you can customize via the [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) web form. I don't think JSF and theming can get any easier than PrimeFaces.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/remove-all-default-css-styling-from-primefaces/

Comment: This doesnt work in my case because it seems that the classes are still rendered by Primefaces... I wanted to remove all style applied by Primefaces, which can be only done by taking away all the classes that PF applies

Comment: Note that the ThemeRoller remark is severely outdated!

Answer (score 15):

PrimeFaces inserts two CSS files by default, `theme.css` and `primefaces.css`. You can remove `theme.css` by putting the following to `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then you can overwrite `primefaces.css` by creating an empty file in:

```
WebContent/resources/primefaces/primefaces.css
```

Answer (score 11):

**Older PF versions (<6.0)**

If you want to use the primefaces with your own css's wouldn't it be easier to create your own theme using the [jQuery UI - ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) ?

Here's a link to how you create your [own Theme for PrimeFaces](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=e7OqkknhEtk#!)

**Newer PF versions (6.0 and up)**

More recently PrimeFaces introduced the ['Designer API'](https://www.primefaces.org/introducing-primefaces-designer-api/) Since PF components have more features, the themeroller is not that suitable anymore. The Designer API is SASS based and allows you to [create really good themes](https://www.primefaces.org/designer-jsf/documentation.xhtml)

Comment: Sugar for the ones who don't know how to program in CSS

Answer (score 4):

Create own theme as @Daniel said. I just want to add :

For partial styling you don't have to firebug everything, primefaces [user guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) covers style classes for each element. It contains also other very useful info and tips (also part about skinning). So use it as your first source when you find yourself struggling with anything about primefaces.