# Is it possible to revert to default Windows look and feel / theme?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, themes

Is it possible to "turn off" or "disable" the current/default Primefaces theme and have the native **Windows** theme be used??

If so, how is this be done?

--For instance, I was trying to find a easy way to revert to standard Windows ***button*** styles/shapes.

Thanks for any help/guidance.

s

Comment: What do you mean by default Windows theme?

Comment: @siebz0r: I believe he actually means "no CSS" and thus browser-specific look'n'feel and that the OP thinks due to ignorance that it's Windows specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Longer answer is that Primefaces comes with a set of themes (you can find the list at http://primefaces.org/themes.html). If you don't like any of them, you can use ThemeRoller to create your own (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). There is a "How-To" in the Primefaces docs. The newest (3.4) is available at http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_4.pdf or you can get for another version at http://primefaces.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off all primefaces styling by setting the following context parameter

```
   <context-param>
     <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
     <param-value>none</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

In your web.xml. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10162179/1530938) by Cagatay, team lead of primefaces