# Removing primeface's css

Tags: css, primefaces

any idea on how to replace primeface default css with my own css (without removing all default css styling of the primeface theme).
                                       Thank you for helping

Comment: Can you put some code?

Comment: Hope this link will help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160892/remove-all-styling-from-primefaces-components

Comment: By creating your own css and loading it in your application. Not any different from how you would do that with other existing stylesheets in .e.g. jquery or whatever

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all styling from Primefaces components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160892/remove-all-styling-from-primefaces-components)

Answer (score 0):

To change the primeface default css you have to put the! important tag in the id or class you want to change. In this way it will take your css and not the default one.

For example

```
.ui-button-text-icon-left .ui-button-text {
    padding: .3em 1em .2em 2.1em !important;
}

.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: 1px solid #E6EDFB !important;
    padding: 4px 10px;
}

.ui-widget-content a {
    color: #0000a0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Bad suggestion... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles. And this is about **removing ALL** css... not overriding individual things.

Answer (score -1):

Here you are example with bootstrap library...
In the example as you can see it will change the color to red only for .btn class thats in the .form-inline class.

Your css must be the last in html header so it override others.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/yzd9o4hc/`
```