# Spring boot Remove default styling of prime faces

Tags: spring-boot, primefaces, stylesheet

I have a spring boot application which uses following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

However every component that i use of prime faces it displays the default prime faces style, i tried:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param> 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>myfaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

in the web.xml
also i tried creating a theme jar and added the same in web xml but there is no change.
Can someone suggest something here running out of ideas currently.

Comment: So if you don't use springboot it is removed? And what is the 'default style'? The default theme or just some styling you do not want? Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160892/remove-all-styling-from-primefaces-components

Comment: i think that is irrespective, it shows up default styling of primefaces which i want to get rid of

Comment: Good luck then... (did you READ the link I posted?)

Comment: as mentioned in the question above i tried the none setting up in the web.xml already

Comment: Read **ALL** answers in the link