# Remove class `ui-state-active` from primefaces button

Tags: primefaces

Im trying to use a combination of resources to remove the `ui-state-active` class from a p:button in primefaces 12.

Is it possible? It worked for `ui-state-hover`.

```
  <p:button
        onmouseover="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover')"  | works fine 
        onmousemove="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover')"  | 
    
        onmousedown="$(this).find('ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active')"
        OR 
        onmousedown="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-active')"

       doesn't work.
   />
```

its there a way to accomplish what i've described? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you like to remove that class?

Comment: Because i have multiple variations of buttons, and my SASS code is shared between a jsf and a angular project. When the style class `ui-state-active` is added by primefaces, then my desired css class is ignored (p:button - styleClass is overrided)

Comment: I was able to overcome this by creating custom selector for the focused / hover state etc, but then i was unbled to solve the issue of having multiple variations os buttons (15+, primary, secundary...). So my latest attempt was remove the style class added by primefaces. But lmk if you think theres a better way of doing this.

Comment: Have you tried including that class in your custom css, to override PF ones? This should be enough to get your result or, for a drastic solution, you can use/try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10162179/6865328)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a viable solution bc i have more then one variation of button, therefore it would only solve my problem for one variation.